# How to use circular progress drawable to add array colors

Tags: android, xml

[CircularProgressDrawable](https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/Progress#circularprogressdrawable)

This is the library i'm using in my project. 
MY APPROACH IS :

```
<com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressviewmain"
        app:pv_progressStyle="@style/Material.Widget.ProgressView.Circular"
        app:pv_circular="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:pv_progressMode="indeterminate"
        app:pv_autostart="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

and Code is :

```
progressView = (ProgressView)findViewById(R.id.progressviewmain);
```

functions are :

```
private void startprogress(ListView listView, ProgressView progressView){
    progressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
    private void stopprogress(ListView listView, ProgressView progressView){
        listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

all of this is working fine but as there in documentation we can see CircularProgressDrawable with 2 different forms i'm not able to get 1st one in which colors are changing . How to give input the array of colors to that ?? how to use attr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it said in [doc](https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/Progress#attributes-1) you can give the view array of colors with `cpd_strokeColors`

> cpd_strokeColors - The array of colors will be used as stroke's color (for indeterminate mode).

**Update 1:**
To change the attributes you have to create a style in `res/values/styles.xml` like this:

```
<style name="CircularProgress">
        <item name="cpd_padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="cpd_initialAngle">0</item>
        <item name="cpd_maxSweepAngle">270</item>
        <item name="cpd_minSweepAngle">1</item>
        <item name="cpd_strokeSize">4dp</item>
        <item name="cpd_strokeColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="cpd_strokeSecondaryColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="cpd_reverse">false</item>
        <item name="cpd_strokeColors">@array/rainbow</item>
        <item name="cpd_rotateDuration">1000</item>
        <item name="cpd_transformDuration">600</item>
        <item name="cpd_keepDuration">200</item>
        <item name="cpd_transformInterpolator">@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator</item>
        <item name="pv_progressMode">buffer</item>
        <item name="cpd_inAnimDuration">0</item>
        <item name="cpd_outAnimDuration">@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime</item>
</style>
```

Then assign it to your view:

```
<com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/progressviewmain"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:pv_autostart="true"
        app:pv_circular="true"
        app:pv_progressMode="indeterminate"
        app:pv_progressStyle="@style/CircularProgress"/>
```

And it will work.

Comment: actually i'm quite newbie so please can you tell me the method to implementation

Comment: Actually how to call cpd_strokeColors ........... from xml or java ? I'm trying to use it in xml i'm not able to do this and also not any method in java named this

Comment: I think it would be like this:
`app:cpd_strokeColors="@color/rainbow"`
while `rainbow` is the name of array of colors in `res/values/colors.xml` and it's like:
    `<array name="rainbow">`
        `<item>@color/bright_pink</item>`
        `<item>@color/red</item>`
        `<item>@color/orange</item>`
        `<item>@color/yellow</item>`
    `</array>`

Comment: <com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressviewmain"
        app:pv_progressStyle="@style/Material.Drawable.CircularProgress"
        app:pv_circular="true"
        app:cpd_strokeColors="@array/rainbow"
        app:cpd_inStepColors="@array/rainbow"
        app:pv_progressMode="indeterminate"
        app:pv_autostart="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
i'm using this but still same bar :(

Comment: @HumzaMalik I just edit my answer.

Look at it and it will fix your problem.

Mark it as answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thankss alot for help it's really working awesome :)